# Workflow and Blog Module issue

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I using the Apostrophe Sandbox because it almost fits my use case.
I added Workflow because I need to have two languages.

Now if i add a Blog Article and want to view it the app crashed with the following error:

```
C:\Users\Gradlon\Desktop\apostrophe\node_modules\apostrophe-workflow\lib\api.js:568
    if (locale.match(/-draft$/)) {
               ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
    at Object.self.draftify (C:\Users\Gradlon\Desktop\apostrophe\node_modules\apostrophe-workflow\lib\api.js:568:16)
    at getTwo (C:\Users\Gradlon\Desktop\apostrophe\node_modules\apostrophe-workflow\lib\api.js:274:70)
    at C:\Users\Gradlon\Desktop\apostrophe\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:718:13
    at iterate (C:\Users\Gradlon\Desktop\apostrophe\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:262:13)
    at C:\Users\Gradlon\Desktop\apostrophe\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:274:29
    at C:\Users\Gradlon\Desktop\apostrophe\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:44:16
    at C:\Users\Gradlon\Desktop\apostrophe\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:723:17
    at C:\Users\Gradlon\Desktop\apostrophe\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:167:37
    at C:\Users\Gradlon\Desktop\apostrophe\node_modules\apostrophe-workflow\lib\api.js:270:16
    at C:\Users\Gradlon\Desktop\apostrophe\node_modules\apostrophe\lib\modules\apostrophe-docs\lib\cursor.js:1086:18
    at C:\Users\Gradlon\Desktop\apostrophe\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:52:16
    at C:\Users\Gradlon\Desktop\apostrophe\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:1209:30
    at C:\Users\Gradlon\Desktop\apostrophe\node_modules\apostrophe\lib\modules\apostrophe-docs\lib\cursor.js:1379:18
    at C:\Users\Gradlon\Desktop\apostrophe\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:52:16
    at Immediate.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Gradlon\Desktop\apostrophe\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:269:32)
    at Immediate.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Gradlon\Desktop\apostrophe\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:44:16)
```

After some testing I narrowed it down to the following lines causing the Error:

```
<div class="demo-blog-author">
  <div class="demo-blog-author-image">
    {% if data.piece._author.thumbnail.items.length %}
      {{ apos.singleton(data.piece._author, 'thumbnail', 'apostrophe-images', { noHeight: true, edit: false}) }}
    {% endif %}
  </div>
  <div class="demo-blog-author-bio">
    {% if data.piece._author %}
        {{ apos.area(data.piece._author, 'body', {
          widgets: {
           'apostrophe-rich-text': {}
         }
       }) }}
    {% endif %}
  </div>
</div>
```

As suggested in the first answer I tried to use the enterpürise Testbed.
https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe-enterprise-testbed
This leads to the same error!
Steps taken
1. Download repo.
2. install modules.
3. Restore MongoDB.
4. Launch app.
5. Add a blog article with an linked author.
6. View the Article (Crash)

Any help in solving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Regards
Gradlon

Answer (score 0):

How do you initialize `apostrophe-workflow`? What options do you pass to it in your `app.js`?

Looks like the locale itself is not set at all in the context: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/apostrophe-workflow#localizing-and-internationalizing-websites

Maybe you still need to run?

```
$ node app apostrophe-workflow:add-missing-locales
```

Also see https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe-workflow/issues/164 for some hints with the same stacktrace.

Good luck!

Comment: I initialize apostrophe-workflow like this: 'apostrophe-workflow': {
      locales: [
        {
          name: 'de-de',
          label: 'Deutsch',
          children: [
            {
              name: 'en-en',
              label: 'Englisch'
            }
          ]
        },
      ],
      defaultLocale: 'de-de',
      // IMPORTANT: if you follow the examples below,
      // be sure to set this
      alias: 'workflow'
    } and i also added the Missing locals. For the providede lin k i wil take a look in to it. but for now i still have the issue.